# Terraform Outputs Map of String as string variable in another module

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Wanted to know how can i use a output (Map of String) as an input(String) to another module. I have a LB module which i create a Azure LB with for_each for multiple backend pools.
moduleLB

```
resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "lb-probe" {
  for_each        = var.lb_settings
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.wv-lb.id
  name            = join("", [var.lb_name, "-inbound-probe-", each.key])
  port            = each.value.port_probe
  protocol        = each.value.protocol_probe
  request_path    = each.value.request_path
  interval_in_seconds = each.value.interval_in_seconds
}
```

variable

```
variable "lb_settings" {
  description = "All the LB Settings"
  type = map(object({
    protocol_probe = string #"Details of load balancer Probe/Healthcheck"
    port_probe    = string
    request_path = string
    interval_in_seconds = string
    protocol_rule = string
    forntend_port = string
    backend_port = string
    backend_pool_name = string
  }))
}
```

Output

```
output "healthprobe_id" {
  value = {
    for k, healthprobe_id in azurerm_lb_probe.wv-lb-probe : k=>healthprobe_id.id
  }
}
```

The Above Output Returned is in below Format

```
health_probe_id = {
  "test1" =  
"/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/lb_name/probes/probe_id"
  "test2" =  
"/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/lb_name/probes/probe_id"
}
```

I want to use the test1 probe id in VMSS as health health_probe_id

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "main" {
  name                            = var.vmscaleset_name
  resource_group_name             = var.resource_group_name
  location                        = var.location
  sku                             = var.virtual_machine_size
  instances                       = var.instances_count
  admin_username                  = var.linux_user_name
  admin_password                  = var.admin_password
  disable_password_authentication = var.disable_password_authentication
  zones                           = var.availability_zones == 0 ? null : var.availability_zones
  zone_balance                    = var.zone_balance
  # custom_data                     = var.vm_cloud_init_data == "" ? null : data.template_cloudinit_config.cloudinit_config[0].rendered
  upgrade_mode                    = var.upgrade_mode
  health_probe_id                 = var.health_probe_id
```

Variables

```
variable "health_probe_id" {
  type = string
  description = "The health Probe ID of the LB used by VMss to do Rolling Updates check"
}
```

My main.tf looks as below

```
module "test1-lb" {
  source = ""
  resource_group_location = var.region
  resource_group_name     = ""
  resource_group_name_platform    = ""
  lb_name                    = ""
  private_ip_address_allocation = "" 
  virtual_network_name          = ""
  subnet_name                   = ""
  api_lb_settings               = {
    test1 = {
      protocol_probe = "" #Details of load balancer Probe/Healthcheck
      port_probe    = ""
      request_path = ""
      interval_in_seconds = ""
      protocol_rule = ""
      forntend_port = ""
      backend_port = ""
      backend_pool_name = ""
    }
    test2 = {
      protocol_probe = "" #Details of load balancer Probe/Healthcheck
      port_probe    = ""
      request_path = ""
      interval_in_seconds = ""
      protocol_rule = ""
      forntend_port = ""
      backend_port = ""
      backend_pool_name = ""
    }
  }



}

module "vmss_test1" {
  source                          = ""
  asset_id                        = ""
  vmscaleset_name                 = ""
  resource_group_name             = ""
  resource_group_name_platform    = ""
  disable_password_authentication = ""
  subnet_name                     = ""
  availability_zones              = []
  instances_count                 = ""
  virtual_machine_size            = ""
  image_name                      = ""
  loadbalancer_name               = module.test1.lb_name    
  loadbalancer_backendpool_name   = "test1"
  location                        = var.region
  public_key_name                 = ""
  virtual_network_name            = ""
  default_cap                     = ""
  max_cap                         = ""
  min_cap                         = ""
  zone_balance                    = true
  tags                            = ""
  health_probe_id = module.test1-lb.healthprobe_id[test1] 
  upgrade_mode = ""
  depends_on = [module.test1-lb]
}
```

I am not sure how  do i access that output in my VMSS module so that it can be passed to different VMSS modules for example test1 output to test1 VMSS and test2 to test2 of VMSS

Comment: "module.moduleA.test[key1] it doesn't work" - please provide complete code demonstrating what you did, and the actual error messages.

Comment: Updated the post. Hope that helps

Comment: You forgot to post the error.

Comment: Sorry I want to understand how can i reference those values. I am not sure how do i set up my code to achieve the scenario which i posted.

Comment: You also haven't provided how you create the modules? Where is "module.moduleA.test[key1]"?

Comment: Added main.tf settings Sorry trying to figure out how best i can explain my requirement/issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want specifically to use `test1`, then it should be:

```
health_probe_id = module.test1-lb.healthprobe_id["test1"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. That did the trick. I feel pretty dumb :) missing quotes :) anyway thanks its working as expected